# Plot groupby data by month

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I'm trying to plot grouped by month `DataFrame`, where index column is `DateTime`.
My goal is to plot all months on separate plots.

```py
index=date_range('2011-9-1 00:00:03', '2012-09-01  00:00:03', freq='10min')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index),3),index=index)
df2 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.month)
df2.plot()
```

This gives me 14 plots (not 12), where 2 first are empty - on the x-axis are years from 2000 to 2010. Than two first plots are January.

Hoping for your good advice how to cope with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? When grouping data you usually aggregate it in some way if you want to plot it. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
index=pd.date_range('2011-1-1 00:00:03', '2011-12-31 23:50:03', freq='10min')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index),3),index=index)
df2 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.month)
for key, group in df2:
    group.plot()
```

**Update:** Fix for groups that span more than a month. This is probably not the best solution but it's the one that first fell on my mind.

```
import pandas as pd

num_ticks = 15

index=pd.date_range('2011-9-1 00:00:03', '2012-09-01  00:00:03', freq='10min')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index),3),index=index)
df2 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.month)
for key, group in df2:
    step = len(group) / num_ticks
    reset = group.reset_index()
    reset.plot()
    plt.xticks(reset.index[::step],
               reset['index'][::step].apply(
                    lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).values,
               rotation=70)
```

Comment: I would only like to have separate plots for each month - I will update my question.

Comment: This works slightly better but looking for 9th plot, the x axis is Nov 2011, Jan 2012, Mar 202, May 2012, Jul 2012 ?

Comment: @Michal Have you copy pasted from my answer or tried it on some other data? Because for this data everything works perfect when I try it out.

Comment: Ok. After I restarted the kernel it works ok but can you also check other period for index (already updated in my question) ?

Comment: @Michal Yes I see the problem when you changed the date range. This is because the 9-nth month range span is a year so it stretches the x axis. For quick fix just do `group.reset_index().plot()` instead of group.plot(). To have a valid `x` axis labels is a little bit more work.

Comment: Thanks, this works. It would be nice to have this feature to plot more than one year, using so simple code.

Comment: @Michal Added a fix that shows the months nicely... Not the best solution probably, but it works...